# Checking Button Captions

Tags: excel, vba

So i am using a form and as the user click on each button it opens a secondary form. when they are done it returns them back to the starting form and changes that particular button caption to "Complete". there are 10 buttons in total and each button will have one of three captions: "Complete", "Not Completed", and "Not Required".  what i am trying to do is when all the buttons do not equal "Not Complete" the form tells you are done and closes.   something to the effect of:

```
if Not (All Buttons) = "Not Complete" then
    Msgbox "You have finished the tasks needed, Thank you"
    Unload Me
End if
```

Comment: Sounds good - is there a specific part which is giving you problems though?  Seems like the place to add this check would be when you change each button caption as the user returns to the form.

Comment: ATS, you need to make a subroutine in your form code that loops through the buttons and checks each one. If it finds a "Not Complete" it can exit back to the form. Otherwise, it displays the msgbox and unloads the form. Once you have this you need to create a LostFocus event handler for each button that calls the subroutine. This way no matter the order your user completes the tasks you're covered. HTH

Comment: ATS, sorry I checked you need a cmdbuttonname_Exit event handler for each button, of course replacing cmdbuttonname with the appropriate name.

Comment: If you post some of your actual code you're more likely to get answers - you already have a form with some buttons, so it would help to see how your existing code looks, along with how your buttons are named etc.